# Sorting folder names in Outlook VSTO

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, vsto

I'm using VSTO to build an Outlook add-in.  I have a wpf TreeView with binding

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}">
```

where Folders comes from a property that is set as

```
Folders = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.Folders;
```

The folder hierarchy shows up correctly, but does not sort alphabetically like it does in Outlook.  I don't see any methods to handle the sort natively.  Just wondering if anyone else has done this and how they pulled it off.

Answer (score 0):

I would sort the list myself.  Assuming you want to sort by folder name, do this:

```
// Get the folders and sort them
SortedList<string, Folder> sortList = new SortedList<string, Folder>();
foreach (Folder nextFolder in this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.Folders)
    sortList.Add(nextFolder.Name, nextFolder);
List<Folder> finalList = new List<Folder>();
finalList.AddRange(sortList.Values);

// Set the sorted list as the source
Folders = finalList;
```

Comment: Doing that would break the hierarchy, correct?  I need the full folder / subfolder hierarchy to be maintained, just sorted.

Comment: Why would it break the hierarchy? Folders still have the same children. It just changes the order of Folder objects in the collection and does not change any member of Folder.  If you need to sort all the child nodes, let me know and I'll edit my answer (a different method would be required).